# Get array of all images in asset catalog folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, asset-catalog

In iOS is it possible to get an array of images (or image names) that are inside a folder of an asset catalog?

If so, how?

I'm not really sure why there is a down vote on this. I really have no idea where to start.

My alternative is to create a plist of all the files in the folders but it just seems redundant.

I can't add any code because what would I add?

Would love to get feedback on why there is a down vote though.

Comment: And why exactly would you like to do this?

Comment: Isn't it possible to iterate through the files in the Images.xcassets-folder?

Comment: @LordZsolt so I can display them in a table for instance. Not sure why it matters though?

Comment: @Mikael sounds promising. Is it just a normal folder in the app bundle? I'll take a look for how to do this.

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm asking since your question is a bit weird. I can't imagine this being needed in any real use case.

Comment: @LordZsolt I assure you my app is very real and I am required to display a list of images in a collection view. This list of images is never updated or changed. It's part of the app bundle. Seems an odd way to answer a question on stack overflow though. If everyone only answered the question they thought would have a valid use case in their own apps then none of the questions would get answered.

Comment: Hmm seems that you need to get in to Assets.car somehow. Not sure if that it possible...

Comment: @Fogmeister, I'm facing a very similar issue to you in my other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564450/how-to-populate-a-uitableviewcell-with-the-correct-resolution-image?noredirect=1#comment43556043_27564450. Have you found the solution, and if so, can you assist me with mine? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Of course, you can read the directories that your app owns, you can create/remove..

You can start reading NSFileManager documentation at
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html

You can download the related source code as examples and see how this is done.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But the asset catalogs are compiled into a `.car` file. That means that there are no folders during runtime....