# How to populate a UITableViewCell with the correct resolution image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have set up a UITableView that contain cells of images.

I am using Asset Catalog to name the images appropriately as image1.png, image1@2x.png, and image1@3x.png.

I have an NSMutableArray that I initialize with the image names from Asset Catalog, for example like so:

viewDidLoad:

```
self.LogoArray = [ [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image1",@"image2", image2", nil];
```

Then I created a Custom Cell with my own custom image to display in the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // some code here

    cell.customImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.LogoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ];

    // some code here
}
```

The problem is when I run this on the different iPhone platforms, the images are really blurry and resolution is bad.

I believe the compiler doesn't know which version of image.png, image@2x.png, or image@3x.png to assign to `cell.customImageView.image` based on what iPhone platform it is running on.

Is there another alternative I should be using to allow Xcode to choose the appropriate image file from Asset Catalog to display it correctly on the different iPhone platforms?

This is how my Asset Catalog looks:
[image]

The objects in the LogoArray are named appropriately with the correct name from Asset Catalog.

Thanks

Comment: what is the name for your xcasset catalog

Comment: Are your image assigned correctly in @ 2x and @ 3x placeholders in  Asset Catalog ?

Comment: I updated my question, please look.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work to me...

Comment: To my knowledge the simulator doesn't ever use the @3x, you have to run it on the device to see them. Its got something to do with how the pixels are rendered on the 6+

Comment: I can confirm that running it on my device does not fix the issue. I ran it on my iPhone 5C and the images are still blurry. If I didn't use Asset Catalog, and initialize my array with image1.png, image2.png, etc. the images display perfectly

Comment: What sizes did you use for @1 @2 and @3 images? For the Barona one. What are the sizes for each image? They all look the same size from the screenshot.

Comment: 2brothers, barona, chase, and crab hut are 200x66, 400x133, and 600x200 appropriately. valley view is 200x65, 400x130, and 600x196

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the name of the file under the Asset Catalog.

In the screenshot you sent, you should just use the names:

```
self.LogoArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"barona_logo", @"chase_logo", @"crabhut_logo", nil];
```

And you should be ok.